# How do I remove /wordpress/ from my permalinks?

Tags: permalinks

I am a newbie, and struggling a little. 
My wordpress file is called 'wordpress' in my root file, so I now have domain.com/wordpress/

How do i get my web address to domain.com/example-page?

Sorry if any of this is not technically sound. As mentioned, im very new and learning as I go!
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have unzipped the wordpress package directly into your web root.
Move everything in the `/wordpress/` folder to the `/` folder (web root) and you should be good.

If you intend to have the installation run out of the `/wordpress/` directory, then update your .htaccess file to look like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```